# How to start a Go Development Server for go app running on App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, gcc, go

I am trying to run a go API app I run the command.

```
dev_appserver.py --port=9999 app.yaml
```

I got the error

```
ERROR    2018-01-05 06:50:27,346 instance_factory.py:196] Failed to build Go application: (Executed command: /home/bitsbridge/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/goroot-1.8/bin/go-app-builder -app_base /home/bitsbridge/go/src/bitbucket.org/bigkittylabs/uout-go/server -api_version go1 -arch 8 -dynamic -goroot /home/bitsbridge/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/goroot-1.8 -gopath /home/bitsbridge/go -nobuild_files ^^$ -incremental_rebuild -unsafe -print_extras_hash server.go)

2018/01/05 12:20:27 Can't find package "C" in $GOPATH: cannot find package "C" in any of:
    /home/bitsbridge/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/goroot-1.8/src/C (from $GOROOT)
    /home/bitsbridge/go/src/C (from $GOPATH)
2018/01/05 12:20:27 go-app-builder: Failed parsing input: parser: bad import "unsafe" in github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3/doc.go from GOPATH
```

My go env is

```
GOARCH="386"
GOBIN="/home/bitsbridge/go/bin"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="386"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/bitsbridge/go"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_386"
GCCGO="gccgo"
GO386="sse2"
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m32 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build008385594=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
```

help me please. thanx in advance.

Comment: Have you tried the [Quickstarts](https://cloud.google.com/go/quickstarts)?

Comment: @VictorHerasmePerez yes, I have tried. fetched a hello world app as described and run. It's working fine.
My google-cloud-sdk is in "home" directory. and app is in /home/go/src/bitbucket.org/bigkittylabs. Do I need any changes related to directory or Cross compiler?

Answer (score 1):

The two errors you mention show that it cannot find:

- package `C`: this mean something you import is using [cgo](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/)
- package `unsafe`: something you import is using [unsafe](https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/)

The [quickstarts](https://cloud.google.com/go/quickstarts) spell out fairly clearly that the standard environment does not allow the use of `unsafe` or `cgo`. You should use the [Flexible environment](https://cloud.google.com/go/getting-started/hello-world) instead.

Comment: I think my app can't be run in flexible environment.
I tried. it says "go run: cannot run non-main package" Do I have to go into each folder contains file which includes main package and then run go run *.go?
If i do that says "panic: exec: "go-bindata": executable file not found in $PATH".
The only I know is that server.go which has app.yaml and index.yaml.
Is there anything I can do to run the app?

Comment: You'll need to write an actual program with a main. Please read [how to write go code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html)

Comment: I know how to write a simple code in golang. I have multiple directories which have .go files in those. How can I know which file is to be run.
I think this app run in standard environment. Please tell me how to run this is standard environment. I am beginner. I don't know about the project but I have to run it. Sounds awkward but I have to. :(

Comment: We can't help you. You need to convert your app to have a main package and function. The subdirectories are probably separate packages used within the program.